# Qual é o atalho no workbench para executar o script todo

Tags: mysql

Sei que o atalho para executar uma linha é ctrl + enter. Mas ate agora nao achei qual é o atalho para executar o script todo.

Comment: A pergunta não faz parte do escopo do site, mas segue resposta-comentário: `control shift enter`. . . Para outros atalhos: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Comment: Avaliar todas as células: `ctrl + r`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelo menu

```
Query -> Execute (All or Selection)
```

Atalho no windows

```
ctrl + shift + enter
```

Atalho no Mac

```
command +shift + enter
```